# This is not a valid source path/URL - Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

So I'm trying to set up git bash but everytime I URL it give a dialogue with "This is not a valid source path/URL - Git Bash". The URL i am using is

```
ssh://trncprop@trncproperty.com:tpcapp.git
```

Is that right? It is a git repo that is hosted on bluehost from my research that is the correct method of connecting. Can you help?

Thanks in advance! Littleswany!

Comment: replace the last `:` with `/`

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work :(

Comment: it would talk to that host.

Comment: sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: i would contact trncproperty.com. we don't know how thats setup.

Comment: I set it up what details do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out with help of a LOAD of research so here is the answer

```
 trncprop@trncproperty.com:/home3/trncprop/git/tpcapp.git
```

You have to put the root path to the repository!

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer with the steps?